# Piping input to getchar() prompts c

Tags: c, ubuntu

Assuming that I have a C program which has the following structure, and which does something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

   int afunction(char *arg) {
     if (strcmp(arg, "something") == 0) {
        return 1;
     } else {
       return 0;
     }
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char ans = 'n';
   if (afunction(argv[1])) {
        printf("The value of your entered parameter was \"something\" \n");
   } else {
        printf("The value of your entered parameter was not \"something\" \n");
        printf("Do you wish to try again? (y/N) ");
        ans = getchar();
        if (ans == 'y') printf("Your answer was y");
        // If this program wasn't a mock up, relevant code to restart would be added.
   }
        return 0;
}
```

This works if I run it manually:

```
foo@test:~$./myprogram goo
The value of your entered parameter was not "something"
Do you wish to try again? (y/N) y
Your answer was y
foo@test:~$
```

However I cannot get it to print "Your answer was y" if I pipe input. I.e.  for all of the following:

```
foo@test:~$echo 'y' | ./myprogram requiredparameter
foo@test:~$echo 'y/n' | ./myprogram requiredparameter
foo@test:~$yes | ./myprogram requiredparameter
foo@test:~$printf 'y/n' | ./myprogram requiredparameter
foo@test:~$printf 'y' | ./myprogram requiredparameter
foo@test:~$./myprogram requiredparameter <<< echo 'y'
foo@test:~$./myprogram requiredparameter <<< echo 'y/n'
foo@test:~$./myprogram requiredparameter <<< printf 'y'
foo@test:~$./myprogram requiredparameter <<< printf 'y/n'
```

My return is:

```
The value of your entered parameter was not "something"
Do you wish to try again? (y/N) foo@test:~$
```

It follows that I have not piped the input correctly, and hence the program exits automatically since it uses the default value of `ans`, which is `'n'`. Why don't these methods work? How can I pipe input to the prompt?

EDIT: For clarity.

EDIT2: The `requiredparameter` does things which aren't relevant to the question, but is required for the executable to run (I think this induced unnecessary confusion). Also, `ans = 'n'` by default, which I should have specified.

EDIT3/4: Made the mock program a bit more believable given the inputs and required parameters.

Comment: Please post more of the relevant code, so we can see the flow of your program, how you handle the input and write the output.

Comment: Quick edit: the program simply returns 0 if the value is not 'y'.

Comment: What's `requiredparameter` ? There's no reference to that in your code. Also, `ans` has not been defined anywhere. Can you post the exact (minimal) code that gave you the unexpected output ?

Comment: iow : running the code you posted with `int ans = 0;` and `#include <stdio.h>` added, should work as you expect, so there's likely something you're doing differently.

Comment: Can you display the value the `ans` value **after** `getchar()`?

Comment: Your update states that `requiredparameter` is necessary for the code to run, but the code you included does not require this (`afunction` isn't called). In fact, the current code won't even compile. So, the code you're running is different from the code you included in the question. We can't help you unless you provide the actual code that causes the problem. When you minimize this code, make sure to run it first, and check if it still has the unexpected behavior, before posting it.

Comment: This is not a valid C program. https://ideone.com/GT64de Do verify what you post.

Comment: What is `arg[1]` ? You need `-n` for the `/n` to work with echo. After removing the `afunction()` and the unused `if` the program works for all cases, except for `<<< printf 'y/n'` as that is HERE-string not command substitution and then `getchar` reads `p`, probably you meant `< <(printf "y\n")` or `<<<"y"$'\n'` or `<<<"y"` or `<<<$(printf "y\n")`

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the issue you're describing - are you sure you tested the code yourself before posting it ?

Comment: With a bit of further research, I came across this: "When you redirect input from  echo "y"  you also redirect the EOF (end-of-file) character that signifies the end of input. So whatever program that you launch after the input is received will receive an EOF character as well." I'm guessing that this is somehow pertinent to the issue. How can I not redirect the EOF character?

Comment: @R.Rengold The mock program works fine for the test cases you have that actually does what they are supposed to do. Perhaps it is the real code you have that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your mock program seems to work fine, and behaves like you wanted it to behave for most of your cases. Perhaps there is a bug in your actual program, but not in the code you did post.

Many of your test cases are wrong though.

```
./myprogram requiredparameter <<< echo 'y'
```

does not run echo y and sends that to stdin. It is the same as if you ran

```
 echo ' ' |./myprogram requiredparameter echo 'y'
```

So your program just reads a space. If you want to do it using the `<<<` operator of the shell, it would be

```
./myprogram requiredparameter <<<$(echo 'y')
```

or just

```
./myprogram requiredparameter <<<y
```

Notice you must not have any space after the <<< there.

I would advice you to also try to debug your code so you can see what is going on, or  add some debugging tracing, such as:

```
ans = getchar();
printf("getchar() read character value %d\n", ans); // debug
if (ans == 'y') printf("Your answer was y");
```

Then you can look up the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) value that getchar returned.

Also write a newline in your printf statements, so change

```
printf("Your answer was y");
```

to

```
printf("Your answer was y\n");
```

That way you can see the output immediately when you run the program in a terminal, otherwise the output from printf gets buffered and is not displayed until you print a newline, or call `fflush(stdout)`, or the program exits normally.